# Update sqlite query not working in Visual Basic 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to insert row and update row (if row already exists), as following -

```
Dim con As SQLiteConnection
Dim sql As String
Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
Dim da As SQLiteDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim NumberOfRows As Integer
    Public Sub UpdateUserStatistics(ByVal UserId As Integer, ByVal QId As Integer, _
                                    ByVal KeyName As String, ByVal KeyValue As Integer)
        con = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source = " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/user_statistics.db;Version=3;")
        con.Open()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM med_user_meta where user_id=" & UserId & " And qid=" & QId
        da = New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "UserMeta")
        NumberOfRows = ds.Tables("UserMeta").Rows.Count
        ds.Clear()
        If (NumberOfRows = 0) Then
            Dim InsertQuery As SQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand
            InsertQuery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO med_user_meta " _
                                 & "(user_id, qid, " _
                                 & KeyName _
                                 & ", timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, datetime('now'))"

            InsertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_id", UserId)
            InsertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("qid", QId)
            InsertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue(KeyName, KeyValue)
            RowInserted = InsertQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ElseIf (NumberOfRows = 1) Then
            Dim UpdateQuery As SQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand
            UpdateQuery.CommandText = "UPDATE med_user_meta SET " _
                & KeyName _
                & " = ?, timestamp = datetime('now') Where qid = ?"
            'UpdateQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_id", UserId)
            UpdateQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("qid", QId)
            UpdateQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue(KeyName, KeyValue)
            RowUpdated = UpdateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

I am using this code in a module and calling `UpdateUserStatistics` wherever required
My problem is that, insert query works fine, **but `update` query does Not work.**

It's been more than 2 hours, but I couldn't find, where am I making mistake?

Also, is there any way to get the final update query into message box after adding parameters, so that I can check if my final update query is correct?

**Edit - 1**

I forgot to mention, value of `RowUpdated` is returning 0, i.e. `ExecuteNonQuery` is Not updating the row.

I have also confirmed that row corresponding to update query Do exists, and the `ElseIf (NumberOfRows = 1) Then` block is running too, but it's Not updating the row.

Comment: So you get the infamous `NotWorkingException` right?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I even tried `try - catch` but, it didn't throw any exception. I am a medical doctor, so don't know programming very well.. so I can't say what this problem is called.

Comment: What is the result of `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Everytime value of `RowUpdated = UpdateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()` is 0, and I confirmed the same after opening the sqlite file in sqlite reader.
I even ran the same query in mozilla firefox sqlite, there it's updating the row

Comment: Then I guess there's no rows matching the `where` condition. Avoid using anonymous parameters. Add the paramters sequentially. Do not use [AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Name the parameters like this: `@name` where `name` if the name of the parameter.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå thanks for the suggestion. can you please provide a sample code for better understanding. and i have checked that row matching `where` condition Do exists (checked the row in mozilla sqlite).

Comment: Did you click and read the link I gave you? Hover `AddWithValue` in my previous comment.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I just read it. I am testing it now. Thanks

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå it's working after making changes as mentioned in link provided by you. thank you very much.